# bind_param() Fatal Error in PHP MySQLi

Tags: php, database, mysqli

So I know this error/question has been posted/asked a lot on SO, but none of the answers helped me and I kept getting this error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object`

Here is the relevant code:

```
    $connect = new mysqli(connection info);

    $search = $_POST["search"];

    $sql = $connect->prepare("SELECT name, seller FROM products
                              WHERE name LIKE '%' + ? + '%';");
    $sql->bind_param("s", $search);


    ?>
```

I believe it has something to do with the like clause, but I am not sure. I am a inexperienced SQL and PHP coder.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: PHP's concatenator is `.` not `+`

Comment: And you don't need to concatenate inside of a string like that, unless you're attempting to use the mysql `CONCAT()` function.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, well that's in the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options: add the wildcard inside the variable, or inside the query.

Inside the query, you use the CONCAT function

```
$sql = $connect->prepare("SELECT name, seller FROM products
                          WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', ? , '%')");
$sql->bind_param("s", $search);
```

Outside of the query, you can pass it in with the bind_param, which is good if you decide you want to do an exact search instead of a wildcard search

```
$sql = $connect->prepare("SELECT name, seller FROM products
                          WHERE name LIKE ?");
$sql->bind_param("s", '%'.$search.'%');
```

If the bind_param does not work, you can add the wildcards before the statement:

```
$search = '%'.$search.'%';
$sql->bind_param("s", $search);
```

Comment: Since the second arg is by reference I wouldn't expect your second example to work.  Can you verify?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, but I can add an addendum...

Comment: I haven't tried the second example but the first one worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to do with the `+`, but if you want `'%$search%'` then:

```
$search = '%'.$_POST["search"].'%';

$sql = $connect->prepare("SELECT name, seller FROM products
                          WHERE name LIKE ?");
$sql->bind_param("s", $search);
```

Answer (score 0):

you put the wildcards into the bind itself like this and use the PHP concatenation operator `.`

```
$sql = $connect->prepare("SELECT name, seller FROM products
                          WHERE name LIKE ?");
$sql->bind_param("s", '%' . $search . '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already show how to fix it, but just to explicitly state it in case you want to know, the reason you got the error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

is that your call to `prepare` failed because of a syntax error in your SQL statement.

While you can use `+` as a string concatenation operator in some other databases, in MySQL it's strictly a math operator, as far as I know.

If you follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/2734189) to configure your connection such that MySQL errors will raise PHP exceptions, you'll be able to see the specific error that MySQL returns instead of just getting a seemingly-unrelated PHP error when you try to use the unsuccessfully prepared statement.

Comment: Noted for the future, thanks